# Dropping multiple tables with same prefix in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have few tables in hive that has same prefix like below..

```
temp_table_name
temp_table_add
temp_table_area
```

There are few hundreds of tables like this in my database along with many other tables.
I want to delete tables that starts with "temp_table".
Do any of you know any query that can do this work in Hive?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no such thing as regular expressions for drop query in hive (or i didn't find them). But there are multipe ways to do it, for example :

- With a shell script :

  ```
  hive -e "show tables 'temp_*'" | xargs -I '{}' hive -e 'drop table {}'
  ```
- Or by putting your tables in a specific database and dropping the whole database.

  ```
  Create table temp.table_name;

  Drop database temp cascade;
  ```

Comment: hive -e ‘show tables 'temp_*’ | xargs -I ‘{}’ hive -e ‘drop table {}’    is not working for me

Comment: The answer is perfect however there is a small change that is needed which actually worked for me. I am modifying @Louxou 's code a bit by adding double quotes. Here is the updated code.
`hive -e "show tables 'temp_*'" | xargs -I '{}' hive -e 'drop table {}'`

Comment: i want to add something to this. The problem now is that hive ( or beeline ) tends to show the results in "graphical" format. Also if you have multiple DB in hive you need to specify the one you need `beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 -e "use <db>; show tables 'temp_*'" | xargs -I '{}' beeline -e 'use<db>; drop table {}'`

Answer (score 9):

Above solutions are good. But if  you have more tables to delete, then running 'hive -e drop table' is slow. So, I used this:

```
hive -e 'use db;show tables' | grep pattern > file.hql
```

use vim editor to open file.hql and run below commands

```
:%s!^!drop table  
:%s!$!;
```

then run

```
hive -f file.hql
```

This approach will be much faster.

Comment: Where do you mention the match table pattern here?

Comment: @Alex Raj Kaliamoorthy  -  grep 'pattern'

Comment: Note that there is space after "drop table", like this: `drop table `.

Answer (score 5):

My solution has been to use bash script with the following cmd:

```
hive -e "SHOW TABLES IN db LIKE 'schema*';" | grep "schema" | sed -e 's/^/hive -e \"DROP TABLE db\./1' | sed -e 's/$/\"/1' > script.sh
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to delete all tables using following steps in Apache Spark with Scala:

```
val df = sql("SHOW TABLES IN default LIke 'invoice*'").select("tableName") // to  drop only selected column
val df = sql("SHOW TABLES IN default").select("tableName")
val tableNameList: List[String] = df.as[String].collect().toList
val df2 = tableNameList.map(tableName => sql(s"drop table ${tableName}"))
```

Answer (score 2):

As I had a lot of tables do drop I used the following command, inspired in the @HorusH answer

```
hive -e "show tables 'table_prefix*'" | sed -e 's/^/ \DROP TABLE db_name\./1' | sed -e 's/$/;/1' > script.sh
hive -f script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

hive -e 'use sample_db;show tables' | xargs -I '{}' hive -e 'use sample_db;drop table {}'

Answer (score 0):

Below command will also work.

```
 hive -e 'show tables' | grep table_prefix |  while read line; do hive -e "drop table $line"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

fastest solution through one shell script:

`drop_tables.sh pattern`

Shell script content:

```
hive -e 'use db;show tables' | grep $1 | sed 's/^/drop table db./' | sed 's/$/;/' > temp.hql
hive -f temp.hql
rm temp.hql
```